# Checkbox in header of expansion panel

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `md-checkbox` component as a title in header of expansion panel like below. In this case when I'm trying to check this checkbox then expansion panel change expanded to false and I cannot check checkbox. How can I fix this issue? I would like to check checkbox and not change expanded expansion panel but after click in header but not on the checkbox then expanded change to false.

```
<md-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
                    <md-expansion-panel-header>
                        <md-panel-title>
                            <section>
                                <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="model.IsActive">Is Active</md-checkbox>
                            </section>
                        </md-panel-title>
                    </md-expansion-panel-header>
                </md-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add $event.stopPropagation as shown below

```
<mat-checkbox ... (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">Is Active</mat-checkbox>
```

Courtesy: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826704/470347)