# Prevent mat-expansion panel from toggling when mat-checkbox in Header clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

Can we prevent Expansion panel from toggling when checkbox inside header is clicked? Somehow stop the event propagation. Right now with below sample code, when the checkbox is clicked, the panel also toggles (opens\closes). Desired state is for expansion panel to toggle, when any area of header is clicked except the checkbox inside the header.

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>
    Panel Title
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
     <mat-checkbox>Edit</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmkqls?file=src/app/expansion-overview-example.html. see also   https://stackoverflow.com/a/56560771/5456789

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can call the stopPropagation $event method when mat-checkbox is clicked:

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>
    Panel Title
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
     <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">Edit</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: Is it the perfect way to stop toggling?

Comment: It's difficult to say... "Perfect" implies serveral things, and this event management, in my opinion is not the most beautiful and perfect way. But trying to answer the comment, yes it is the "best" way to stop toggling

Comment: Thank you sir, it also just worked perfectly for me with a mat select

Comment: @Kalamarico What if i had and `input` instead of `checkbox` and i only want to disable `pointer event` for first time when input is click no all time

Comment: @Awais bufff, in a "fast thinking..." you can set in (click) a function that executes the "$event.stopPropagation" and redefines itself after that, for example: "this.myFunc = () => {}" you know? First execute the stopPropagation and after redfines itself as an empty function so, the first time click it will stop propagation and redefines itself as empty so the second click will do nothing

Comment: @Kalamarico can you explain that function a little-bit please as I am new to Angular material.

Comment: @Awais sorry for the delay. I have implemented in a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c28mx2 It's more simple than my first comment, I use a counter. In an expansion panel, in the title I set an input element, and I have implemented your requested funcionality. Hope it helps ;)
As you can see, the first click not expand the panel, the others (second, third, etc) will expand.