# How to prevent toggling mat-expansion-panel by clicking mat-expansion-panel-header?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I know mat-expansion-panel-headers is a button. clicking anywhere on that button toggles the expansion opens/closes. But I don't want to let users click anywhere on the header and open it. There should be a small button. One click on that button will open/close the expansion panel. How can I do that?

I have tried this, but it didn't work.

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <mat-panel-title>
    MENU
  </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: as a hack, you could try toggle the state on click, so the the open state will go from close to open and back to close quickly, before the DOM is ever updated, you get me?

Comment: I was thinking that as my last tool. But I don't think its the best idea. It would be best if I could prevent the default behavior of `mat-expansion-panel-behavior`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can play with toggle function:

```
<mat-expansion-panel >
<mat-expansion-panel-header #panelH (click)="panelH._toggle()">
  <mat-panel-title>
   <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu" (click)="panelH._toggle()">menu </i>
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>

  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gy3hx2)

Comment: Nice, because this solution works with mat-slide-toggle and stopPropagation does not work

Answer (score 50):

amir's solution works in some cases but I was having some animation issues with the arrow. I found the solution here to be more consistent and overall I think its better:

[Prevent mat-expansion panel from toggling when mat-checkbox in Header clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826525/prevent-mat-expansion-panel-from-toggling-when-mat-checkbox-in-header-clicked/49826704)

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>
    Panel Title
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
     <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">Edit</mat-checkbox>
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

this for example will prevent the header expanding when clicking the checkbox

Comment: Nice! Also works on the `mat-panel-description` itself (in my case I had some buttons rendered inside `mat-panel-description` and clicks on those were unnecessarily toggling the panel state - possibly some kind of event bubbling - and `stopPropagation` on `mat-panel-description` stopped it; rather than having to do `stopPropagation` on each button separately)

Comment: This is more helpful in my case as with `_panelH._toggle()_`, the function in the `(opened)='function1()'` is even though called and just the panel is not expanded.

Answer (score 2):

you can disable toggle partially , for example prevent toggle only in button

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
        <span>
           Text
        </span>
        <button class="mat-button course-btn"(click)="onChangeCourseBotton($event)">disabled area</button>
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>


  onChangeCourseBotton(e: Event) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

You can also do this inline:

```
   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
         <span>
            Text
         </span>
         <button class="mat-button course-btn"(click)="$event.preventDefault()">disabled area</button>
      </mat-panel-title>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: it works but only when clicking the button. If I use `(keyup.Enter)="$event.preventDefault()"` it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Prevent Clicking the toggle in perticular button in mat-expansion-panel-header.

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header #exppanel">
 <mat-panel-title>
  <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu </i>
 </mat-panel-title>
 <mat-panel-description>
  <button (click)="!exppanel._toggle()">CLICK</button>
</mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

**using this you can prevent clicking on perticular element (click)="!exppanel._toggle()"**
it may help someone. Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Closing the panel immediately after the default behaviour works for me.

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel [hideToggle]="true" (opened)="doSomething()">
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>Menu</mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

TS file

```
@ViewChild("panel") panel;

doSomething() {
  //do stuff
  this.panel.close();
}
```