# how to make it when click on mat-panel-description don't expand panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic-native

How can I make the `mat-expansion-panel` expand only when the user clicks on the `mat-panel-title`, not the `mat-panel-description`?

```html
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle (expanded)="item.panelOpenState" *ngFor="let item of matchList; let i = index" #matchListPanel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            <div class="match-descriptions">
                <span class="league">{{ item.leagueTitle }}</span>
                <span class="title">{{ item.title }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="!matchListPanel.expanded">unfold_more</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="matchListPanel.expanded">unfold_less</mat-icon>
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description *ngIf="!matchListPanel.expanded">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `event$.stopPropagation()` isn't working.
I think you can follow this approach as mentioned in this solution:

[How to prevent toggling mat-expansion-panel by clicking mat-expansion-panel-header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558900/how-to-prevent-toggling-mat-expansion-panel-by-clicking-mat-expansion-panel-head)

Comment: not working will click on mat-panel-description still expanding.